# How to escape single quote in EJS template

Tags: ejs

my variable contains a string with an apostrophe or a **single quote '**

i'd like to display it with EJS.

I use

```
<img class="card-img-top" src='<%= data[i][0].omdb.Poster %>' alt='<%= data[i][0].omdb.Title; %>'>
```

When **data[i][0].omdb.Title;** contains an apostrophe, HTML is broken.

**<%=** is known to escape html. But not single quote!
How to do it? Any idea please?

I can't find anything on ejs doc.

Answer (score 0):

> `<%=` is known to escape html. But not single quote! How to do it?

Use double quotes around your attributes. Then single quotes won't matter.

(If you really want to use `'` then you can do `...Poster.replace(/'/g, "&apos;")`).